# To access EASA amc s or FAR gm?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa

How can I access EASA Acceptable Means of Compliance documents, or FAR guidance material docs ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on exactly what you need but the FAA makes pretty much everything available online. [You can start here](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/) for most stuff and get directly to the [Federal Aviation Regulations here](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14tab_02.tpl). If you prefer paper you can [take a look here.](https://bookstore.gpo.gov/search/products?keywords=FAA%20)

Comment: Sir I checked your links burt still I couldnot find the Guidance Material which I heard about as a material to decide on means of compliances .

Comment: @denizcanelçi The FAA calls its AMC documents Advisory Circulars (AC). They're the first link on the Regulations and Policies page.